# page.tpl.php override for Panels Pages?

Tags: panels, theming, 7, debugging

I want to use a specific tpl.php file for all Panels Custom pages.

I get some formatting issues if I try to use "Panels Everywhere" module, so would like an alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a template_preprocess_page function to add your custom tpl for Panels page. Here's how:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_page().
 */
 function MODULEORTHEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if (module_exists('page_manager') && count(page_manager_get_current_page())) {
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__panels';
    }
 }
```

Then create a page--panels.tpl.php for your custom Panels page.

Answer (score 0):

@arshacn answer is correct, as the question is to affect all panel pages, but if you need a separete tpl, or only affect a few, for any contentype do this:

```
// ads theme-hook-nodetype-suggestions
      function MYMODULEORMYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
        if (isset($vars['node']->type)) {
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $vars['node']->type;
        }
    }
```

this will add "page--yourcontentype.tpl.php" suggestion, then create a page--yourcontentype.tpl.php for every contentype needed, place tpl file in your subtheme template folder.