# How exactly do I create a variation of a .tpl file?

Tags: 7, theming

I am new to Drupal and am working on a partially complete site. There's a .tpl file I wish to duplicate and alter and have only be used with a certain Panel Page type ('Product Page').

I've read [Drupal's documentation about template suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/223440#custom-suggestions), but am not sure what to actually do.

I've placed the following in my template.php file:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['???']) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = 'new_tpl_file';
  }
}
```

But I've got no idea what to put in `$variables['']` so that the suggestion appears on my pages. I know my Panels page is called 'Product Pages' but that's it. Is there a machine name for that I can use as a variable? Would it work if it was something like:

```
      if ($variables['product_pages']) {
```

Does anyone know of a tutorial or guide out there? Im pretty lost here. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to override panel page template then I am afraid you are using the wrong hook, `hook_preprocess_node` works for node pages only.

However panel page goes through `hook_preprocess_page`, so you can add custom template suggestion in following way.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_page().
 */
 function MODULEORTHEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if (module_exists('page_manager') && count(page_manager_get_current_page())) {
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'custom__panel';
    }
 }
```

Then create `custom-panel.tpl.php`

Reference: 
[page.tpl.php override for Panels Pages?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78613/page-tpl-php-override-for-panels-pages)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be in the right direction, but no luck here. I still dont see the template suggestions.